# Banco de dados não está conectando!

Tags: javascript, mysql, mvc, design-pattern

O meu banco de dados não está conectando.
Ao fazer um refctoring do meu código seguindo o padrão MVC o banco de dados parou de funcionar.

Segue link com os arquivos para teste:
https://github.com/LeonardoVini/node-refctoring

app.js

```
const app = require('./config/server')

// port must be set to 9095 because incoming http requests are routed from port 80 to port 9095
app.listen(9095, function () {
    console.log('Node app is running on port 9095');
});
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const consign = require('consign')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors(corsOptions))

consign()
    .include('app/routes')
    .then('config/dbConnection.js')
    .then('app/models')
    .then('app/controllers')
    .into(app);

module.exports = app;
```

dbConnection.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql')

const connMySQL = () => {
    return mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'eqix1998',
        database: 'quotedb',
        port: 3306
    });
}

module.exports = () => {
    return connMySQL;
}
```

Routes > quotes.js

```
module.exports = (application) => {
    application.get('/quotes', (req, res) => {
        application.app.controllers.quotes.quotes(application, req, res);
    });
}
```

Controllers > quotes.js

```
module.exports.quotes = (application, req, res) => {
    var connection = application.config.dbConnection();
    var quotesDAO = new application.app.models.QuotesDAO(connection);

    quotesDAO.getQuotes((error, results) => {
        res.send(results)
    });
}
```

Models > quotes.js

```
function QuotesDAO(connection){
    this._connection = connection;
    console.log(this._connection)
}

QuotesDAO.prototype.getQuotes = (callback) => {
    this._connection.query('SELECT * FROM quotes', callback)
}

module.exports = () => {
    return QuotesDAO;
}
```

Árvore de arquivos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: é bem possível que esteja atrelado ao fato da conexão ser uma função assíncrona.

Comment: Seria legal você colocar o código no Github ou em algum outro local para que possamos baixar e deixar as coisas mais faceis, para mim parece haver um problema na forma como você está fazendo o Export do module do connMySQL, mas só vou ter certeza testando o código.

Comment: Segue o link: https://github.com/LeonardoVini/node-refctoring

Comment: Uso o angular para o front-end.
Estou sentindo falta de um função connect().
Eu tenho um código funcionando, mas todo bagunçado sem seguir nenhum designer Pattern e lá eu executava essa função.
Entretando não conseguir fazer funcionar nesse caso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifiquei o seu código e fiz as alteracões que funcionaram comigo.

Segue elas:

- Primeiro, ali no prototype, nao use *arrow-function*, pois o `this` não irá referenciar ao objeto `QuotesDAO`, mas sim a um objeto global qualquer.

  Ficaria assim:

  ```
   QuotesDAO.prototype.getQuotes = function(callback){
     this._connection.query('sua query', callback);
   }
  ```
- Segundo, se não funcionar, no seu arquivo de conexão com o banco, `dbConnection.js`, faca o seguinte:

  ```
  const connMySQL = mysql.createConnection({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'root',
   password: 'eqix1998',
   database: 'quotedb',
   port: 3306
  });
  connMySQL.connect(function(erro){
   if(erro)
    return console.log(erro);
    console.log('Conectou!');
  });

  module.exports = () => connMySQL
  ```

  O método `connect` irá tentar fazer a conexão com o banco e informar se houve sucesso. No método que você escreveu, se colocar um *console.log* irá aparecer a mensagem `disconnect`:

  ```
  console.log(connMySQL().state); // disconnect
  ```

Comment: funcionou aqui! Bastou alterar de arrow function para function que rodou normalmente.
Muito obrigado.